# How to troubleshoot a printer that wont boot

Tags: printer, bootable-media, hp-laserjet

I've got an HP LJ Enterprise M604 that fails to turn on.

-I have verified that the wall outlet works and is distributing the correct amount of wattage

-I have verified that the cable works with other devices

It might be worth mentioning that before it wouldn't turn on at all, it would turn on occasionally. I'm not sure why though. I unplugged it and let it sit for 10 minutes before attempting to boot it again. With luck, it did indeed boot, but as soon as I tried printing a test page it shut off.

I realize I might be facing some hardware repair,(which is fine) but I dont have a spare test-motherboard to use.

How can I troubleshoot a printer that wont turn on?

Answer (score 1):

> It might be worth mentioning that before it wouldn't turn on at all, it would turn on occasionally. I'm not sure why though. I unplugged it and let it sit for 10 minutes before attempting to boot it again. **With luck, it did indeed boot, but as soon as I tried printing a test page it shut off.**

From my experience, it sounds as though the fuse has blown or the internal power supply to the printer has stopped working properly.  The power required to boot up and spin all of the wheels isn't a lot of power, but when you start up the heating elements, (fuser and such), then the power draw might be too much for the power supply to keep the device running at all.  If it's not under warranty, then you could probably open it up to see if the fuse has blown or if there's any visible damage to the power supply.

Comment: Alas, it was the PSU. I found a new one online, fairly inexpensive, and was able to boot normally after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's connected to a network, try running it as a stand-alone printer off of usb. Otherwise, it sounds like you've isolated your potential problems well, but are having very unpredictable behavior. Unfortunately, I think you may be out of luck and have a "declared dead" printer on your hands. If it's under warranty, then you'll have to do an RMA/return. Otherwise, a service call from a repair tech may be an option, but may cost about the same as getting a new printer; they tend to focus on enterprise copier/scanner/printers, but you may find exceptions.

Comment: I'm almost certain that  a new motherboard would do the trick. Can you think of anything else besides the MB that might be prohibiting booting?